# Unable to send notification from Facebook App with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface, facebook-php-sdk

```
I am trying to send Notification to the User , when certain event gets hit .
```

I have used following code to send Notification , But i am getting a error. Please let me know where i am doing a mistake

### Code:

`$fb_response = $facebook->api(
                           '/' . $user_id . '/notifications', 'POST',
                            array(  'access_token' => $facebook->getAppId() . '|' .             $facebook->getApiSecret(), 
             'href' => "My_facebook_app_URL",
         'template' => "My Message",
 ));`

### **Error:**

```
FacebookApiException Object
(
    [result:protected] => Array
        (
            [error] => Array
                (
                    [message] => (#10) Notification send blocked.
                    [type] => OAuthException
                    [code] => 10
                )

        )

    [message:protected] => (#10) Notification send blocked.
    [string:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$facebook->getAppSecret()
```

Instead of

```
$facebook->getApiSecret()
```

maybe?